# Update ipadUrl property on flowplayer

Tags: ipad, flowplayer

Please, help me update stream on flow player. I initialize my player with ipad plugin

```
$f('hit_video', 
    {
        src: "http://bs.orsk.ru/flowplayer.swf",
        wmode: "opaque",
    },
    { 
        plugins: {
            rtmp: {
                url: "http://bs.orsk.com/flowplayer.rtmp.swf",
                netConnectionUrl: "rtmp://streamurl/live/anystream.stream"
            },
        }, 
        clip: {
            provider: "rtmp",
            url: "anystream.stream",
            live: true,
            scaling: "fit",
            ipadUrl: "http://streamurl/live/anystream.m3u8",
            autoPlay: true,
        }
    }).ipad();
```

And then I try to do this

```
$f('hit_video').play([{
          url: 'rtmp://streamurl/live/newstream.stream'
        }]);
        $f('hit_video').getClip(0).update({
            url: "newstream.stream", ipadUrl: "http://streamurl/live/newstream.m3u8"
        });
```

It works on desktop, but doesn't work on iPad. Stream is not updated. How to change stream?

Comment: What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: "rtmp://streamurl/live/newstream.stream" and "http://streamurl/live/newstream.m3u8"  are expected, and rtmp is updated successfully. But m3u8 saves the first setting  "http://streamurl/live/anystream.m3u8"